# How can I create table in custom tkinter

Tags: tkinter, canvas, customtkinter

Im pretty new in (custom)tkinter and would like to ak how can I create table and put there data. Data is coordinates of points which I create in canvas, this data is also stored in list. It should be possible to read the table and change values there. If its possible to create this kind of table without class it would be great.
Now I create textbox in which is one coordinate stored, but I have problems with reading the values from this textboxes.

Thank you for your help.

```
import customtkinter as tk
tk.set_appearance_mode("light")
tk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")
root = tk.CTk()
root.geometry("800x900")
root.title("The test GUI")
first_colour = "lime green"
second_colour = "navy"
def join_polygon1(event):
    canvas.create_line(points1[0], points1[1], points1[-2], points1[-1], width=3, fill= first_colour)
frame1 = tk.CTkFrame(master=root)
frame1.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill="both", expand=True)
title = tk.CTkLabel(master=frame1, text="Polygon creation GUI", font=("Roboto", 24))
title.pack()
canvas = tk.CTkCanvas(frame1, width=600, height=350, bg="white")
canvas.pack(pady=10)
global points1
points1 = []
frame = tk.CTkFrame(frame1)
frame.columnconfigure(1, minsize=120)
frame.columnconfigure(2, minsize=120)

x_coor1 = tk.CTkLabel(frame, text="x coor. polygon 1     |", text_color=first_colour)
x_coor1.grid(row=0, column=1)
y_coor1 = tk.CTkLabel(frame, text="y coor. polygon 1     ", text_color=first_colour)
y_coor1.grid(row=0, column=2)


def polygon1(event):
    global first_polygon
    x1 = event.x
    y1 = event.y
    r = 5
    circle1 = canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x1 + r, y1 + r, fill=first_colour, outline=first_colour)

    points1.append(x1)
    points1.append(y1)

    frame = tk.CTkFrame(frame1)
    frame.columnconfigure(1, minsize=100)
    frame.columnconfigure(2, minsize=100)
    text1 = tk.CTkTextbox(frame, height=1, width=90, text_color=first_colour)
    text1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    text1.insert("0.0", str(points1[-2]))

    text2 = tk.CTkTextbox(frame, height=1, width=90, text_color=first_colour)
    text2.grid(row=0, column=2)
    text2.insert("0.0", str(points1[-1]))
    frame.pack()

    if len(points1) > 2:
        first_polygon = canvas.create_line(points1, width=3, fill=first_colour)
        root.bind("<Return>", join_polygon1)

frame.pack()

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", polygon1)
canvas.bind("<Button-3>", polygon2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how big does this table need to be (number of rows, number of columns)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Treeview` widget from `tkinter` package and include it inside your `customtkinter` frame something like this:

```
headers2=['#', 'Name']
    _tree=tk.ttk.Treeview(master=frameCustom,height=25,columns=headers2,show='headings')
    _tree.heading('#', text='#')
    _tree.heading('Name', text='Name')
    _tree.pack()
    cursor = ((u"1", u"Name A"),
              (u"2", u"Name B"))
    for row in cursor:
        _tree.insert('', 'end', values=row)
        for i, item in enumerate(row):
            _tree.column(headers2[i],width=col_width,anchor=tk.CENTER)
```